# Adding "more-information"-button to woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In standard Woocommerce on the products page of the shop has a nice "add-to-cart"-button. I wanted to add a "more-information"-button to it in the same style.

Using the code from [this page](https://www.pootlepress.com/2014/10/replace-add-to-cart-button-woocommerce-shop-page/#) I managed to add a button by placing this code in my functions.php:

```html
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','more_information');
 
function more_information() {
 global $product;
 $link = $product->get_permalink();
 echo do_shortcode('<br>[button class="meer-informatie" link="' . esc_attr($link) . '"]meer informatie[/button]');
}
```

It's crucial I add a class to the button I want to add so I can style it. Point is I added the button (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU0ia.png)) but the link isn't working. It needs to link to the productdetail-page. So, where does it go wrong? I can't seem to figure it out (but then again: I only speak PHP a little).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the output of the href in the button?

Comment: The output in this version is #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't really know what is wrong with the code I posted in my question but I found something that actually works. Someone might someday be looking for this or encounter the same issue so I'm going to post this as an answer to my own question. After seeking help in all kinds of directions I came up with the following code:

```js
function more_information() {
global $product;
if ($product){
$url = esc_url($product->get_permalink() );
echo '<a rel="nofollow" href="' .$url .'" class="meer-informatie">meer informatie</a>';
}
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','more_information');
```

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to localize the string following Wordpress [guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
function more_information() {
global $product;
if ($product){
$url = esc_url($product->get_permalink() );
    echo '<div class="bottone-cat"><a rel="nofollow" href="' .$url .'" class="tt_button tt_primary_button">';
    echo __('More Information','woocommerce');
    echo '</a></div>';
    }
}
```

I tested it with WPML and it works fine.